# Problema ao realizar upload de imagens

Tags: php, file-upload

Tenho um formulário dentro de uma tabela, e ela vai duplicando as linhas quantas vezes eu quiser, segue:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">*Titulo</th>
            <th width="15%">*Posição</th>
            <th width="60%">*Imagem</th>
            <th width="10%"><a class="adicionarCampoImagem" title="Adicionar imagem" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" style="color: #a6ce39 !important;"></span></a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="linhasImagem">
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="txttituloImagem[]" id="txttituloImagem[]" class="form-control" maxlenght="15">
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="number" name="txtposicaoImagem[]" id="txtposicaoImagem[]" class="form-control" min="1" max="" maxlenght="4">
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="file" name="txtimagem[]" id="txtimagem[]" class="form-control" maxlenght="15">
            </td>
            <td><a class="removerCampoImagem" title="Remover Imagem" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E no PHP o seguinte código:

```
$diretorio = "../../main/paginas/imagens/".$idProduto;
$diretorio = mkdir($diretorio, 0777);
if(is_dir($diretorio)){ 
    $msg = "Não foi possivel criar a pasta da imagem";
}else{
    echo $qtdImagem= count($_FILES['txtimagem']);
    $tabela="imagens";
    for ($controle = 0; $controle < count($_FILES['txtimagem']['name']); $controle++){

        echo $destino = $diretorio."/".$_FILES['txtimagem']['name'][$controle];
        $dados = array(
            'produtos_id' => $idProduto,
            'titulo' => $tituloImagem[$controle],
            'url' => $destino[$controle],
            'sequencia' => $posicaoImagem[$controle]
        );
        $sql_ins_imagens_resultado = adicionar($tabela, $dados);
        if($sql_ins_imagens_resultado){
            if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$controle], $destino)){
                $msg = buildMessage('upload', 'imagens');
            }else{
                $msg = buildMessage('uploadError', 'imagens');
            }   
        }


    }
}
```

O problema é que ao dar um `echo` no `count()` ele esta dando como ZERO e acaba não entrando no `for`. Qual seria meu erro? esta correto o jeito de fazer upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se seu form contem este atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
Ficando assim:

```
  <form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```